# Do not share cookies between domains, only to API

Tags: cookies

I'm trying to set up this kind of architecture:

[image: Domain relationships]

`customer.app.com` & `admin.app.com` are websites, each of them are consuming the API (`api.app.com`)

I have `httpOnly` in each of these websites, basically storing `accessToken` & `refreshToken`.

Example: When I'm logging into `admin.app.com`, these cookies are set in the browser (don't look at the domain, it's my dev environment):

[image: Example cookies]

The issue is, when I go to `customer.app.com`, the same cookies are *also* set. How do I have two separate "sessions" of cookies?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is more of  software design choice and something you might get better answers for on a different stack exchange site, maybe webmaster, stack overflow or  https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I believe the cookies are scoped by origin, but you could configure a gateway to  all three domains so that the browser thinks they share the same origin.